# Which model can be better to classify colinear independent variables?

Tags: python, regression, spss, non-linear-regression

I'm having the following problem.

I have one dependent variable (y) and 200 linear independent variables. However, some of them are related (exists multicollinearity). Therefore, I can't use multivariable linear regression. I tried using ridge regression but I'm facing the problem that my R^2 = 10%.

My y variable represents the concentration of an element:

```
y =[0,013; 0.450;0.556; 1.356;2,222] (not binary)
```

There are any other useful model that could help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Then the title of the question is a bit misleading? There's no classification involved.. So if the predictors are correlated, a general linear model might force some of them to zero.. Ridge might not offset this correct, since it sets coefficients to near zero.

Comment: Assuming there is some useful information in your independent variables, maybe first check whether your response is normal? If not so, maybe scale it and use a lasso etc?

Comment: Welcome to Stack-Overflow! This is a statistics question and we answer programming questions here... Please move your question to [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: thanks @eli-k, I just ask here  because I also tried to implement these algorithms in python, and didn't knew the site you mentioned!

Answer (score 0):

Lasso, or *L<sub>1</sub>* regularization, is a common approach to selection of variables in the presence of collinearity, and it can be applied in linear or generalized linear models. Partial least squares (PLS) is another popular technique for linear models.